# How to make DropDownButton items Window rounded in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, dropdownbutton

1. There is the actual `DropDownButton` with the text and the arrow
2. And there is the window containing `DropDownButtonItem`(s) that opens
   up when we click on the `DropDownButton`.

What I am asking is how to make (2) rounded. Making (1) rounded is easy with `ClipRRect` or `ShapeDecoration`.

I can not get a hold of the window widget that opens up (2) in a variable so that I can tweak it.